# RPATH no longer respected for indirect dependencies

Tags: linux, gcc, ld, glibc, ldd

I have upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 17.10, which moves me from:

- `gcc`: from `gcc-5.4.0` to `gcc-7.2.0`
- `ld`: from `ld-2.26.1` to `ld-2.29.1`.
- `glibc`: from `2.3` to `2.6`

I am building a binary with a hard-coded `RUNPATH`, pointing to the location of some vendor-supplied shared libraries.

```
$ readelf -d /home/steve/src/krx/tests/krx.test | grep RUNPATH
 0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)        Library runpath: [../library]
```

On **`Ubuntu 16.04`** the `RUNPATH` allowed us to locate the libraries.

```
$ ldd ./krx.test
    ...
    libinisafeNet.so => ../library/libinisafeNet.so (0x00007f35c7754000)
    libiniCore.so => ../library/libiniCore.so (0x00007f35c5bea000)
    libiniPKI.so => ../library/libiniPKI.so (0x00007f35c5952000)
    libiniCrypto.so => ../library/libiniCrypto.so (0x00007f35c56e6000)
```

On **`Ubuntu 17.10`** it no longer works

```
$ ldd ./krx.test
    ...
    libinisafeNet.so => ../library/libinisafeNet.so (0x00007fb4acc38000)
    libiniCore.so => not found
    libiniPKI.so => not found
    libiniCrypto.so => not found
```

Setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` **does** allow the libraries to be found

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=../library
$ ldd ./krx.test 
    ...
    libinisafeNet.so => ../library/libinisafeNet.so (0x00007fa787659000)
    libiniCore.so => ../library/libiniCore.so (0x00007fa785a86000)
    libiniPKI.so => ../library/libiniPKI.so (0x00007fa7857ee000)
    libiniCrypto.so => ../library/libiniCrypto.so (0x00007fa785582000)
```

**`LD_DEBUG` for Ubuntu 16.04**

I set `LD_DEBUG=all` and ran `ldd` against my binary.

Here is an excerpt for `libiniCore.so`:

```
 30438:     file=libiniCore.so [0];  needed by ../library/libinisafeNet.so [0]
 30438:     find library=libiniCore.so [0]; searching
 30438:      search path=../library/tls/x86_64:../library/tls:../library/x86_64:../library          (RPATH from file ./krx.test)
 30438:       trying file=../library/tls/x86_64/libiniCore.so
 30438:       trying file=../library/tls/libiniCore.so
 30438:       trying file=../library/x86_64/libiniCore.so
 30438:       trying file=../library/libiniCore.so
```

The library is successfully located, and as can be seen from the `search path` section, it is using **`RPATH from file ./krx.test`**.

**`LD_DEBUG` for Ubuntu 17.10**

I set `LD_DEBUG=all` and ran `ldd` against my binary.

Here is an excerpt for `libiniCore.so`: (it now uses the system search path, not the `krx.test RPATH`)

```
 20027:     file=libiniCore.so [0];  needed by ../library/libinisafeNet.so [0]
 20027:     find library=libiniCore.so [0]; searching
 20027:      search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
 20027:      search path=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/haswell/x86_64:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/haswell:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/haswell/x86_64:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/haswell:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/haswell/x86_64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/haswell:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/haswell/x86_64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/haswell:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/lib/tls/haswell/x86_64:/lib/tls/haswell:/lib/tls/x86_64:/lib/tls:/lib/haswell/x86_64:/lib/haswell:/lib/x86_64:/lib:/usr/lib/tls/haswell/x86_64:/usr/lib/tls/haswell:/usr/lib/tls/x86_64:/usr/lib/tls:/usr/lib/haswell/x86_64:/usr/lib/haswell:/usr/lib/x86_64:/usr/lib            (system search path)
 20027:       trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/haswell/x86_64/libiniCore.so
 20027:       trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/haswell/libiniCore.so
 20027:       trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/libiniCore.so
 20027:       trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/libiniCore.so
 20027:       trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/haswell/x86_64/libiniCore.so
 20027:       trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/haswell/libiniCore.so
 20027:       trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/libiniCore.so
 ...          ...
 20027:       trying file=/lib/x86_64/libiniCore.so
 20027:       trying file=/lib/libiniCore.so
 20027:       trying file=/usr/lib/tls/haswell/x86_64/libiniCore.so
 20027:       trying file=/usr/lib/tls/haswell/libiniCore.so
 20027:       trying file=/usr/lib/tls/x86_64/libiniCore.so
 20027:       trying file=/usr/lib/tls/libiniCore.so
 20027:       trying file=/usr/lib/haswell/x86_64/libiniCore.so
 20027:       trying file=/usr/lib/haswell/libiniCore.so
 20027:       trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64/libiniCore.so
 20027:       trying file=/usr/lib/libiniCore.so
```

So it seems the behaviour of `ld` has changed, and since it is an **indirect dependency** (`krx.test` --> `libinisafeNet.so` --> `libiniCore.so`) the `RPATH` for `krx.test` **is no longer used**.

**Question:**

- Is this a regression?
- Is the only way around this (without updating `ld.so.conf`) to set the `RPATH` on my shared libraries too?
- Is there a way to set the `RPATH` on my binary so that it can locate the indirect dependencies?